# Hibernate detecting if an object is transient with concurrent persistence

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to detect if an object is transient..if it is not I want to update via Hibernate.

Usually I do this by checking if the id has been set but I am worried this is not thread safe and I  have another thread which is saving the object and its possible that the id is not set but the Hibernate is already in the process of saving the object.

How can I do this in a thread-safe way?

Thanks.

```
public void updateIfNotNew(PersistentObject a){
//if another object is in the process of saving....this update will not get persisted
    if (a.id!=null){  
        session.update(a);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you are worried about concurrent updates then you need locking (either pessimistic or optimistic).

Comment: How about using saveOrUpdate() method?

Comment: I dont want to save it...only update it if it has already been saved.

Comment: @Nathan I'm not worry about concurrent updates...I'm worried about how to concurrently check if an object is transient

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend you to look for the interface `org.hibernate.Session` there you can find the method **contains**, this method will look if the given object it's associated with that session (persistent), if not, doesn't mean that it's detached, because it could be associated with other session if any.

Comment: Will that method return true before it persists the object? The exact race condition I'm worried about is that the object has been sent to the DB for persistence but is not contained in the session. That means when my other thread updates the object...the change will not be persisted.

Comment: yes See here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html