# Grails/GORM/Hibernate:List of the properties of a domain instance which reference unsaved transient instances

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am constantly doing things wrong and getting unsaved transient instance exceptions in Grails.  I cannot paste the code, and if I did you would probably just tell me to stop programming for ever.  But here is the generic situation I would like some help with:

I call `instanceOfMyComplicatedDomainClass.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` and grails/hibernate gives me the ubiquitous:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: soexample.SomeOtherDomainClass
```

What can I do (other than understanding my own code) to see which property is the problem given I have several with the same class?  I want a method I can call just before the `.save()` which will `println`/`log`/whatever the **name** of the property that's causing all the huff.  Let me make an example:

```
class MyComplicatedDomainClass {
  SomeOtherDomainClass dataContents
  SomeOtherDomainClass moreDataContents


  static constraints = {
    dataContents(nullable:true)   
    moreDataContents(nullable:true) 
  }      
}

class SomeOtherDomainClass {
  String randomData
}

...

def someRandomMethodAnywhere(){
  def newComplicated = new MyComplicatedDomainClass()
  def imUnsaved = new SomeOtherDomainClass(randomData:'lalala')
  def imOK = new SomeOtherDomainClass(randomData:'lalala2').save() 
  newComplicated.dataContents = imUnsaved
  newComplicated.moreDataContents = imOK
  //At this point newComplicated references an unsaved transient, "imUnsaved".  If I try to save newComplicated it will fail.
  def badPropertyList = findUnsavedTransients(newComplicated)
  assert badPropertyList.contains("dataContents")  //So findUnsavedTransients method returns a list of the names of the properties referencing the unsaved transients
}
```

How would I go about writing the findUnsavedTransients?  Is there any method already in Hibernate that will do a similar thing?

I am asking something different from my other question to list ALL unsaved transients everywhere: [Get a list of all objects grails is planning to magically save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944004/grails-get-a-list-of-all-objects-grails-is-planning-to-magically-save)

Also, I see (and have read) the ~15 other "Hibernate: unsaved transient..." questions, and I am asking for a generic solution to see what the problem is, rather than a specific solution to what I am doing wrong in today's particular snippet.  Teach a man to fish... so to speak.

Comment: Wow i really botched the title as far as making a good SEO perma-link

Comment: remove the failOnErrorrs and print domainInstance.errors after calling save()

Comment: I thought for a second I was overlooking something so obvious, but its the same message, and I still can't tell which property it is that's the problem.

Comment: Try the `contains()` of the session. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752519/hibernate-detecting-if-an-object-is-transient-with-concurrent-persistence

Answer (score 2):

Burt posted something interesting about that today.

www.burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1570

Checkout the hibernate listener.